# check if airflow task is running first time

Tags: python, airflow

I am writing a airflow dag with postgres operator.
I need to perform a one time operation in each task if the task is running first time.
How can we do this?

Comment: Airflow does not provide any way to find whether task has run or not outside the given dag run.

You can query the task_instance table and find an entry of task in it. But a custom script would be required and seems a hacked approach.

You should change your workflow design or elaborate the use case here.

Comment: At first run I want to copy some base data to postgres table and on second run onwards different data will be copied.
Is there any way to get the dag start date and current execution date in the task or total number of times dag ran?

Comment: IMO you should create two dags.  one DAG with schedule='@once' and other with periodic interval. trigger the DAG with schedule='@once'  in your first run (identify it outside airflow) and then let the other dag do its scheduled activity

Comment: but I need to do the same for multiple tables for which I have separate tasks.

If I can get to know about first run I can modify the query accordingly.

Comment: you can access the start date and execution date for each dag_run in the context (kwargs) object. You can base your decision on it then. Implement a flag which is set on first run and pass it as dag parameter

Answer (score 1):

If knowing if it's the first DAG run is good enough to infer it's the first task run as well then you could do the following:

Make a subclass for the `PostgresOperator` and do something like what's done [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/operators/python_operator.html) with `provide_context` in the `PythonOperator` class and its init code.

This will allow you to pass the execution macros to your task as a dictionary in kwargs (in an argument called context in the cited PythonOperator example above). You can then access 'prev_ds' or one of the other 'prev_' prefixed macros specified [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/macros.html).

If the value is None for any of these 'prev_' prefixed items, then you know it's the first DAG run (and very likely the first task run).

In your subclass you can override the `execute` function like this:

```py
def execute(self):
  if self.context['prev_ds'] is None:
    # DO WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DO ON FIRST RUN HERE
  super().execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

**The optimum way to achieve this***(as im trying to achive this with one of my merge dags that depends on the previus run but it isnt there so should be ignored in first run)* **is to make your dag use "pass parameters from the CLI" or "pass trigger configs in GUI"**

follow these steps:

1-create an if-else condition in your python file to check if parameter is been passed choose different route.
for example, you have `key1` set to `null`, if its null it should go to route B, but in your way running it with trigger or CLI you pass a value, now it can go to route A.

2- use bellow code as an example to access the value passed to dag:

```
def run_this_func(ds, **kwargs):
    print("Remotely received value of {} for key=message".
          format(kwargs['dag_run'].conf['message']))


run_this = PythonOperator(
    task_id='run_this',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=run_this_func,
    dag=dag,
)
```

3- for first run use pass parameter or trigger technique that ive mentioned

for example : `airflow trigger_dag -c '{"key1":1, "key2":2}' dag_id`

Answer (score 0):

I tried the other methods and did not work for me when using Airflow 2.0.2 with Bitnami Airflow helm chart. The below code block helped me identify first dag run. get_task_instances() is a DAG class function which you can find under https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/models/dag.py. Note that the current function is taken from Airflow 2.0.2. Do the respective changes in the later versions if needed.

```
def run_this_func(ds, **context):
    prev_task_instances = context["dag"].get_task_instances(
        start_date = context["prev_execution_date"] - timedelta(minutes=60),
        end_date = context["prev_execution_date"]
    )
    if not prev_task_instances:
        print("This is the first DAG run")
    else:
        print(ds)

run_this = PythonOperator(
    task_id='run_this',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=run_this_func,
    op_kwargs={
        "ds":"demo"
    },
    dag=dag,
)
```

The above code applies for schedule_interval other than "@once".
For schedule_interval "@once" change the if condition like this :

```
if context["prev_execution_date"] is None:
     print("This is the first DAG run")
else:
     print(ds)
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for an answer in 2024 - prev_attempted_tries field  of task instance can be used.

Example using Taskflow API:

```
@task
def test_task(ti=None):

    if ti.prev_attempted_tries < 2:
        print('this task is executed first time')
    else:
        print(f'this task was previously executed {ti.prev_attempted_tries-1} times already')

    raise AirflowException('test')
```